# Count the hits in a chained chart

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, linqpad

I'm new in LinqPad. I already solved all my problems except the following:

[image]

How can I get the `.Count()` of one column, respectively the list in the one cell. Like you see in the picture.

My code example is:

```
var test2 = (from d in DocumentTypeLabels 
             select new {d.DocumentTypePIMID, d.Name, d.DocumentType.Documents}
            )
           .Take(1); test2.Dump();
```

My idea was:

```
var test2 = (from d in DocumentTypeLabels 
             select new {d.DocumentTypePIMID, d.Name, (d.DocumentType.Documents).Count()}
            )
            .Take(1); test2.Dump();
```

but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This could not compile because of name of your anonymous type property. `Count = (d.DocumentType.Documents).Count()` is OK.

Comment: I tried that, but I got this error: "NotSupportedException: Constructing or initializing instances of the type.........with the expression d.DocumentType.Documents.Count() is not supported."
Maybe because I work with C# Statement(s)?

Comment: What is the underlying type of object Documents? What is the Linq provider of Documents? Can you show your class definition to us?

Comment: I'm embarrassed, because I don't know which information exactly you need. The code I've written above is the only thing I have in my Query.

Comment: I entered your code in Program template query in Linqpad with simple classes definition and executes successfully. your error is compiler error or run-time error? Is `Documents` is `ICollection<T>`, an if it is include T definition in your question.

Comment: From the NotSupportedException message, it sounds like you are using some unusual Linq Provider, for example OData (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091652/is-there-a-general-method-to-check-whether-a-property-define-supported-by-a-linq )

Comment: Ok that could be the reason, becaus my connection shows me https://......com/Odata.

Comment: I got it now. The problem was that you cannot do this in C# statements, but it works in C# expression :)

Comment: That makes no sense... if it works in C# Expression mode, it will work in C# Statements mode. There must be some other difference in your query.

Comment: Joe Albahari, you're right, after it works in expression its suddenly works in statements too. )

Answer (score 0):

Given the type of `DocumentType.Documents` is a Collection, you could try using the `Length` or `Count` properties from you collection and name a property on your result. For sample:

```
var test2 = (from d in DocumentTypeLabels 
            select new {
                 d.DocumentTypePIMID, 
                 d.Name, 
                 DocumentsTotal = d.DocumentType.Documents.Count()
            }).Take(1);
```

When you do not define a name for a property on the `select` statement, it will generate a property with a name of the property you have provided. For sample: `x.Name` will be `Name` on result.

Comment: I tried that but I got that error: "Cannot execute text selection: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection...does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type ....."

Comment: Try `.Count()` instead of `.Length`.